# How to Launch macOS instance in Google Cloud Platform? I am in need of mac instance to run xcode build of xamarin ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, google-cloud-platform

I need help in launching macOS instance in Google cloud. I do not see any documentation online. Please help

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [an apple.com discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7525945):

> The Apple software end-user license agreement (EULA) only permits OS X operations on Apple hardware, and Google is almost certainly not running Apple hardware here.    So... no.   If you want to host your own server, consider [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.com/) or some alternative running on UNIX, BSD or Linux, or select one of the hosting providers that offers Apple hardware such as [MacMiniColo](https://macminicolo.net/) / [MacStadium](https://www.macstadium.com/)

Comment: Do consider providing references when quoting information from another source. Your answer is copied from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7525945

Comment: Thanks @VishwasM.R, I edited it to use Markdown quoting now.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible on public cloud via AWS today, and the pricing is quite prohibitive: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/mac/

You could also use a colo service as mentioned in other answers such as macstadium.

You can also use GitHub action runners, although those are only small virtual machines - so only useful for low performance use cases